# Why is the spark save job is having 4 stages?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am  trying to save the Dataframe to HDFS location. But my save is taking a long time. The action before this is joining two tables using Spark SQL. Need to know why the save is having four stages and how to improve the performance. I have attached the stage list here [Spark UI Image of the job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJsNe.png).
I have also attached the snippets of my code.

Spark code:

This function gets the data from the main class and the models variable gets table info data from a XML.Intially it gets the data for the source table and then tries to retreive the data from the other join tables.

```
    def sourceGen(spark: SparkSession,
                minBatchLdNbr: Int,
                maxBatchLdNbr: Int,
                batchLdNbrList: String,
                models: (GModel, TModel, NModel)): Unit = {
    val configJson = models._3
    val gblJson = models._1
    println("Source Loading started")
    val sourceColumns = configJson.transformationJob.sourceDetails.sourceSchema
    val query = new StringBuilder("select ")
    sourceColumns.map { SrcColumn =>
      if (SrcColumn.isKey == "nak") {
        query.append(
          "cast(" + SrcColumn.columnExpression + " as " + SrcColumn.columnDataType + ") as " + SrcColumn.columnName + ",")
      }
    }
    var tableQuery: String =
      if (!configJson.transformationJob.sourceDetails.sourceTableSchemaName.isEmpty) {
        if (!batchLdNbrList.trim.isEmpty)
          query.dropRight(1) + " from " + configJson.transformationJob.sourceDetails.sourceTableSchemaName + "." + configJson.transformationJob.sourceDetails.sourceTableName + " where batch_ld_nbr > " + minBatchLdNbr + " and batch_ld_nbr <= " + maxBatchLdNbr + "or batch_ld_nbr in ( " + batchLdNbrList + " )"
        else
          query.dropRight(1) + " from " + configJson.transformationJob.sourceDetails.sourceTableSchemaName + "." + configJson.transformationJob.sourceDetails.sourceTableName + " where batch_ld_nbr > " + minBatchLdNbr + " and batch_ld_nbr <= " + maxBatchLdNbr
      } else {
        if (!batchLdNbrList.trim.isEmpty)
          query.dropRight(1) + " from " + gblJson.gParams.sourceTableSchemaName + "." + configJson.transformationJob.sourceDetails.sourceTableName + " where batch_ld_nbr > " + minBatchLdNbr + " and batch_ld_nbr <= " + maxBatchLdNbr + "or batch_ld_nbr in ( " + batchLdNbrList + " )"
        else
          query.dropRight(1) + " from " + gblJson.gParams.sourceTableSchemaName + "." + configJson.transformationJob.sourceDetails.sourceTableName + " where batch_ld_nbr > " + minBatchLdNbr + " and batch_ld_nbr <= " + maxBatchLdNbr
      }
    if (minBatchLdNbr == 0 && maxBatchLdNbr == 0) {
      tableQuery = tableQuery.split("where")(0)
    }
    println("Time"+LocalDateTime.now());
    val tableQueryDf: DataFrame = spark.sql(tableQuery)
    println("tableQueryDf"+tableQueryDf);
    println("Time"+LocalDateTime.now());
    println("Source Loading ended")
    println("Parent Loading Started")
    val parentColumns = configJson.transformationJob.sourceDetails.parentTables
    val parentSourceJoinDF: DataFrame = if (!parentColumns.isEmpty) {
      parentChildJoin(tableQueryDf,
                      parentColumns,
                      spark,
                      gblJson.gParams.pSchemaName)
    } else {
      tableQueryDf
    }
    println("tableQueryDf"+tableQueryDf);
    println("Parent Loading ended")
    println("Key Column Generation Started")
    println("Time"+LocalDateTime.now());
    val arrOfCustomExprs = sourceColumns
      .filter(_.isKey.toString != "nak")
      .map(
        f =>
          functions
            .expr(f.columnExpression)
            .as(f.columnName)
            .cast(f.columnDataType))
    val colWithExpr = parentSourceJoinDF.columns.map(f =>
      parentSourceJoinDF.col(f)) ++ arrOfCustomExprs
    val finalQueryDF = parentSourceJoinDF.select(colWithExpr: _*)
    println("finalQueryDF"+finalQueryDF);
    println("Time"+LocalDateTime.now());
    keyGenUtils.writeParquetTemp(
      finalQueryDF,
      configJson.transformationJob.globalParams.hdfsInterimPath + configJson.transformationJob.sourceDetails.sourceTableName + "/temp_" + configJson.transformationJob.sourceDetails.sourceTableName
    )
    println("PrintedTime"+LocalDateTime.now());
    println("Key Column Generation Ended")
  }
```

The below code is used to retrieve the data from joining tables.

```
private def parentChildJoin(tableQueryDf: DataFrame,
                              ptJoin: Array[ParentTables],
                              sparkSession: SparkSession,
                              gParentSchema: String): DataFrame = {
    if (ptJoin.isEmpty) {
      tableQueryDf
    } else {
      val parentJoin = ptJoin.head
      val columns = new StringBuilder("select ")
      for (ptCols <- parentJoin.columns) {
        columns.append(
          ptCols.columnExpression + " as " + ptCols.columnName + ",")
      }
      val statement = columns.dropRight(1)

      if (!parentJoin.pSchemaName.isEmpty) {
        statement.append(
          " from " + parentJoin.pSchemaName + "." + parentJoin.pTableName)
      } else {
        statement.append(" from " + gParentSchema + "." + parentJoin.pTableName)
      }
      println("Time"+LocalDateTime.now());
      println("parentJoin.pTableName"+parentJoin.pTableName);
      val pQueryDF =
        if (parentJoin.pTableName.equalsIgnoreCase("order_summary_si_fact_t")) {
          val ordCalDt = "ord_cal_dt"
          val distinctDates = tableQueryDf
            .selectExpr(ordCalDt)
            .distinct
            .collect
            .map(_.getAs[String](0))
          sparkSession.sql(statement.toString).where(col(ordCalDt).isin(distinctDates: _*)).distinct
        } else {
          sparkSession.sql(statement.toString).distinct
        }
      println("Time"+LocalDateTime.now());
      //val pQueryDF = sparkSession.sql(statement.toString).distinct
      println("statement-"+parentJoin.pTableName+"-"+statement);
      parentChildJoin(
        tableQueryDf.join(pQueryDF,
                          parentJoin.pJoinCondition.map(_.sourceKey).toSeq,
                          parentJoin.joinType),
        ptJoin.tail,
        sparkSession,
        gParentSchema)
    }
  }
```

This is the function for writing into HDFS.

```
    def writeParquetTemp(df: DataFrame, hdfsPath: String): Unit = {
    df.write.format("parquet").option("compression", "none").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(hdfsPath)
  }
```

Spark submit configuration:

```
    /usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/spark2/bin//spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 30G --executor-memory 25G --executor-cores 6 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true --conf spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=774857600 --conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max.mb=512 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=40 --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer --conf spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString=true  --conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=36000 --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=500
```

Comment: You will need to actually post the code not just the spark submit statement for anyone to help you.

Comment: Added the code..

Answer (score 0):

From the `attached Image` Looks like => You are doing a `repartition` on **Dataset1(1277 partitions)** after Reading It =>

Stage 10 -> Read and Set Stage Boundary for a 'compressed' dataset having 1277 total number of files * block size into each file (approximated to max available cores) => Shuffle write

Stage 11 -> Shuffle This dataset as Per default spark.sql.shuffle.partitions which is set to 500

Stage 12 -> Read and create Stage Boundary for the second Dataset having 348 total number of files * block size into each file (approximated to max available cores) => Shuffle Write

Stage 13 -> Join These Two Datasets and Save in HDFS  as Per default spark.sql.shuffle.partitions which is set to 500

With Code we can see where it is going bad but last join has huge `Shuffle R%ead` so probably you want to lower your Default Shuffle Partitions.